# $.getJSON hits fail but returns text

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using `$.getJSON` to get JSON from the same domain. I'm getting a `parsererror` but it returns the response text. I can't figure out why i'm getting the `parsererror`. I have included my code below and example of the JSON I am requesting. I may be over looking something simple.

```
      var getDataLink = $timeline.attr('data-timeline-fpid');
      var dataLink = "panel-pane/timeline/json/" + getDataLink + "?jsoncallback=?";

      $.getJSON(dataLink, function(data) {
        var dataMate = data;
      }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error " + textStatus);
            console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
     });
```

JSON:

```
      {
        "button": {
            "text": "dfasfsdf",
            "link": "dsfsadfdsfsdfds"
        },
        "stages": [
            {
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "eventName": "dfasfdsfd",
                        "body": "afdsfasdf",
                        "dateStart": "10 Sep 2015"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "dsafdsf",
                "strapline": "dfadsfasd",
                "dateStart": "Sep 2015",
                "dateEnd": "Sep 2015",
                "body": "dsfasdfasdf",
                "icon": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

EDIT (now working):

```
var getDataLink = $timeline.attr('data-timeline-fpid');
  var dataLink = "panel-pane/timeline/json/" + getDataLink + ".json";
  var res;

  $.get(dataLink, function(data) {
    res = data;
  }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error " + textStatus);
        console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
    }).success(function() {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

Comment: Are you **sure** this is your Json? Have you attached [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check the HTTP?

Comment: The JSON you posted is valid, are you sure that responseText is equal to the JSON?

Comment: console.log output: incoming Text {"button":{"text":"dfasfsdf","link":"dsfsadfdsfsdfds"},"stages":[{"steps":[{"eventName":"dfasfdsfd","body":"afdsfasdf","dateStart":"10 Sep 2015"}],"title":"dsafdsf","strapline":"dfadsfasd","dateStart":"Sep 2015","dateEnd":"Sep 2015","body":"dsfasdfasdf","icon":null}]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not requesting JSON, but JSONP when using `jsoncallback=?` in your url. When your server responds with JSON where JSONP was expected, that results in a parse error. Omit that parameter from the URL.

Comment: No, that's not the reason. A JSONP request can't result in a parsing error message, because there is no code that parses it that can report the error. The JSONP is loaded using a script tag and is parsed when the script is executed. A JSON response to a JSONP results simply in the JSON response being parsed as an object literal and nothing more happens.

Comment: @Guffa: Except that an object literal (that the JSON is interpreted as) is not a valid script, and throws a `SyntaxError`. Of course, *some* JSON is a valid statement, but all that consists of a non-empty object are not.

Comment: Yes, you are right that it causes a syntax error, but how would that end up in the `error` callback, and the response in the `jqXHR` object, when there isn't any XHR request?

Comment: I thought that jQuery adds an `onerror`  handler to the `<script>` tag that would receive this. Not sure, `$.ajax` inner workings have always been a mystery to me. It could as well be that it requests JSONP via XHR for same-domain requests and then evals them.

Comment: The documentation for the error property says *"This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests."*. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ I'm not sure if it counts as a cross-comain call because it has a callback in the URL.

Comment: Nah, OP has a same-domain call (with a relative path), I'd expect jQuery to figure that out correctly.

Comment: It seems so, but I found this that specifies the opposite: *"However, since JSONP and cross-domain GET requests do not use XHR, in those cases the jqXHR and textStatus parameters passed to the success callback are undefined."* http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ Maybe a change in behaviour, and the documentation is outdated?

Comment: @Guffa: yeah, something like that, or just inaccurate docs. Or the OP really had a different problem, and avoiding JSONP still helped him. We don't really know.